# Using GLM to load obj files

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

I am having some difficulty loading in texture coords from the obj file using the GLM library

Using OpenGL 3.3

http://www.cs.manchester.ac.uk/ugt/COMP37111/glm/glm.h
http://www.cs.manchester.ac.uk/ugt/COMP37111/glm/glm.c

I am under the impression that an obj file would have the same number of indexed (none repeated) vertexs as texture coords then the "GLMtriangle: Struct" would contain the vertexs "GLuint tindices[3]" that index the texturecoord array "texcoords". However the examples I have found do not have an equal number of texture coords to vertexs.

Using the above understanding I try to put all the texture coords in to an array by looping through each GLMtriangle and adding indexed texture coords to an array. To give me a texture coord for every single vertex.

*C++ based pseudo code.*

```
for (the number of GLMtriangles)

    t= (the GLMtriangle index ) 

    //vertex0
    rawTextCoords[t] = GLMmodel->texcoords [GLMtriangle.tindices[0]];
    rawTextCoords[t+1] = GLMmodel->texcoords [GLMtriangle.tindices[0]+1];
    //vertex1
    rawTextCoords[t+2] = GLMmodel->texcoords [GLMtriangle.tindices[1]];
    rawTextCoords[t+3] = GLMmodel->texcoords [GLMtriangle.tindices[1]+1];
    //vertex2 
    rawTextCoords[t+4] = GLMmodel->texcoords [GLMtriangle.tindices[2]];
    rawTextCoords[t+5] = GLMmodel->texcoords [GLMtriangle.tindices[2]+1];
od
```

This is my current output.

[image: glm problem]

Comment: Since you're already using a mesh loader, have you considered using one that actually [processes the mesh well?](http://assimp.sourceforge.net/). Open Asset properly sets up the mesh into triangles, ready for uploading and rendering.

Comment: I load the vertexs and indexs from the same obj loader,  I have to use glm obj loader for the assignment

Comment: Seems to me that `GLMmodel` represents the data pretty raw. You cannot use the vertex indices to look up tex coords. You need the tex indices (`tindices`).

Comment: edit.. i was useing vindices in the code, I have now changed that, however the output is much the same.(I have edited the post to match my code)

Comment: Check `t`. Why divide by `3`? What's the tri index?

Comment: Sorry, Ive fixed that now. I loop through the number of vertexs tri*3 and then /3 to get the index of the triangle. I will edit the code to make it a bit clearer.

Im useing the same loop to index to the elementArray.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sample pseudocode at least looks sound.

Wild guess: you are not passing the proper values to `glTexCoordPointer()` (or `glVertexAttribPointer()`).  It's easy to get the `size` or `type` values wrong if you type too fast.  From your pseudocode `size` needs to be 2.

Comment: im almost 100% certain that my buffering is fine I buffer them just after my vertexs, do you know anywhere that has a sphere.obj that works? I'm using a one that the lecture have that has a different number of texture coords to vertexs which just seems wrong.

Comment: This is perfectly fine. Faces index into the vertex and tex coords and what-not array and may even have more than three vertices; you'd need triangulation then.